# LocalDate in array gives me null result

Tags: java

I have an array of Rentals for my Book program. Date of Return must be not null. The date in LocalDate.parse must show up.

```
public class Rent implements {
    private LocalDate dateOfRent;


    public Rent(LocalDate dateOfRent) {
       dateOfRent = LocalDate.now();
 }


 public LocalDate getdateOfRent(){
           return dateOfRent;
         }

     public void setLocalDate(LocalDate dateOfRent){
           this.dateOfRent = dateOfRent;
         }


public String toString() {
        return "Date of Rent:" + dateOfRent;
    }
}
```

My rental array

```
Rent rentals = {
LocalDate.parse("2008-05-16")
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your constructor argument has the same name as your field `dateOfRent` you have to use `this.dateOfRent` to reference the field, otherwise you are assigning the value to the argument variable. So change this:

```
    public RentApp(LocalDate dateOfRent) {
        dateOfRent = LocalDate.now();
    }
```

with this:

```
    public RentApp(LocalDate dateOfRent) {
//      this.dateOfRent = LocalDate.now(); // DON'T YOU WANT TO USE THE ARGUMENT?
        this.dateOfRent = dateOfRent;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @qwerty Tip: Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) will **colorize your code** to show one color for `dateOfRent` the argument being passed and a different color for `dateOfRent` the member variable defined on the class. Noticing that color shows you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Rent(LocalDate dateOfRent) {
       dateOfRent = LocalDate.now();
 }
```

You are "resetting" the local parameter `dateOfRent`, not setting the member.  Try:

```
this.dateOfRent = LocalDate.now();
```

This is known as [parameter shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

(btw: why even have the parameter?)